# Constructing a measure space given the definition of a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, borel-sets, pushforward

Suppose:

- $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a (complete) measure space,
- $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel space associated to $\mathbb{R}$, and
- $f:(X,\mathcal{S})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})$ is a measurable function.

Given this information, is it possible to construct the measure space $(Y,\mathcal{T},\lambda)$ defined by:

- $Y=f(X):=\{f(x):x\in X\}\subset\mathbb{R}$,
- $\mathcal{T}=f(\mathcal{S}):=\{f(A):A\in\mathcal{S}\}\subset\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$,
- $\lambda=f_*(\mu)$ (i.e. the pushforward of $\mu$ by $f$).

If possible, do we need to consider the completion of $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ for the above statement to hold?

Thank you,
Frederick

Comment: Measurable  functions do not map Borel sets to Borel sets n general.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks. How about providing a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{S}$ such that $\mathcal{T}=f(\mathcal{S})\subset\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$. Would this fix the problem of defining $(Y,\mathcal{T},\lambda)$ as indicated above?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, you can not expect that $f(\mathcal{S}):=\{f(A):A\in\mathcal{S}\}\subseteq\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$.

Here is a simple counter-example:

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{S}=2^\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ the counting measure. Then
$(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a complete measure space. Consider the function $f:(X,\mathcal{S})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})$ defined by $f(x)=x$.  It is easy to see that $f$ is a measurable function. Now, take any $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $E \notin \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$. Then $E\in 2^\mathbb{R}$ and $f(E)=E \notin \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$. So
$f(\mathcal{S})\nsubseteq\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$.

So to do what you want to do, you need to define the $\sigma$-algebra in different way. Let us see it.

Let us construct the measure space $(Y,\mathcal{T},\lambda)$ defined by:

- $Y=f(X):=\{f(x):x\in X\}\subset\mathbb{R}$,
- $\mathcal{T}:=\{A \cap Y:A\in\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\}$,
- $\lambda=f_*(\mu)$ (i.e. the pushforward of $\mu$ by $f$).

Note that, for any $E\in \mathcal{T}$ there is $A\in\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ such that $E=A \cap Y$ and $\lambda(E) = \mu(f^{-1}(A))$.

Note that $\lambda$ is well defined. In fact, given $E\in \mathcal{T}$ and  $A_1, A_2\in\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ such that $E=A_1 \cap Y=A_2 \cap Y$, then
$f^{-1}(A_1)=f^{-1}(A_2)$ and so $\mu(f^{-1}(A_1))=\mu(f^{-1}(A_2))$.

Comment: Indeed, this is the construction of $\mathcal{T}$ I was looking for. Thanks! Isn't this equivalent to write: $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\cap Y=\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\cap\{Y,\emptyset\}$. And thus, because the intersection of two $\sigma$-algebras is again a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mathcal{T}\subset\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @FrederickLeuchte , 1. Note that $Y$ does not need to be in $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$. 
2. What do you mean by $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R} \cap \{Y, \emptyset\}$ ? If you mean realy interserction then $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R} \cap \{Y, \emptyset\}=\{Y, \emptyset\}$ or $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R} \cap \{Y, \emptyset\}=\{\emptyset\}$, depending whether  $Y$ is or is not in $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @FrederickLeuchte , 3. The intersection of two $\sigma$-algebras on the **same set** is a $\sigma$-algebra. This may not be the case of $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R} \cap \{Y, \emptyset\}$, since $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{Y, \emptyset\}$ is a  $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$. 
4. Note that defining $\mathcal{T}:=\{A \cap Y:A\in\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\}$, then $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $Y \in \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. You're right... Do you think it is notationally okay to write $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\cap Y$ as the shortcut for $\mathcal{T}=\{A\cap Y:A\in\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\}$? In the same way, one writes $\mathcal{O}_A=\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{R}\cap A$ for the relative topology on $A\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, we could write  $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R} \cap Y$ as a shortcut for $ \mathcal{T}=\{A \cap Y:A\in\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\}$.